# DropShadowEffect and OuterGlowBitmapEffect animation is Taking Too much CPU and Memory usage?

Tags: wpf

Animating the DropShadoweffect and OuterGlowBitmapEffect is keep on increasing the memory and CPU usage. Why it is taking too much memory and cpu usage and is there any way to reduce or avoid?

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="Storyboard1">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" 
        Storyboard.TargetName="textBlock" 
        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Effect).(DropShadowEffect.BlurRadius)"
    RepeatBehavior="Forever">
            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="0"/>
            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.9000000" Value="25"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

    </Storyboard>
</Window.Resources>
<Window.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource Storyboard1}"/>
    </EventTrigger>
</Window.Triggers>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Text="Drop Shadow Effect" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="189,126,0,0" FontWeight="Bold">
        <TextBlock.Effect>
            <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="5" BlurRadius="0"/>
        </TextBlock.Effect>
    </TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no such class as *OuterGlowEffect*.

Do you mean *OuterGlowBitmapEffect*? If so, this is a deprecated class with known performance issues, which could explain your problem. Use *BlurEffect* or another *DropShadowEffect* instead to achieve what you want. (Also, ensure you are not using the deprecated *DropShadowBitmapEffect*.)

But it could also be an issue with your code, in which case, post it up!